# prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to a} g_1(t)f_1(t) + g_2(t)f_2(t) = \lim_{t \to a}(g_1(t)+g_2(t))f_1(t)$

Tags: real-analysis

$a \in R$
, If 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to a}\left( g_1(t) + g_2(t)\right)~~exist, ~~when ~~g_1(t)+g_2(t) > 0$$
and
$$\displaystyle \left(\lim_{t \to a} f_1(t)\right) = \left(\lim_{t \to a}f_2(t)\right)>0$$

then
$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to a} g_1(t)f_1(t) + g_2(t)f_2(t) = \lim_{t \to a}(g_1(t)+g_2(t))f_1(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider $f_1=0,\, f_2(t)=t$ and $a=0$. Define $g_1(t)=-g_2(t)=\frac1t$ when $t\ne0$ (and pick any values of $g_1(0)$ and $g_2(0)$ at will). We have
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \left[g_1(t)f_1(t) + g_2(t)f_2(t)\right] = -1
\neq 0 = \lim_{t \to 0}(g_1(t)+g_2(t))f_1(t).
$$

Comment: ok, i get it. I have edited already.